# "printf -v" inside function not working with redirected output

Tags: linux, bash, unix

With bash 4.1.2 and 4.3.48, the following script gives the expected output:

```
#!/bin/bash

returnSimple() {
   local  __resultvar=$1
   printf -v "$__resultvar" '%s' "ERROR"
   echo "Hello World"
}

returnSimple theResult
echo ${theResult}
echo Done.
```

Output as expected:

```
$ ./returnSimple
Hello World
ERROR
Done.
```

However, when stdout from the function is piped to another process, the assignment of the `__resultvar` variable does not work anymore:

```
#!/bin/bash

returnSimple() {
   local  __resultvar=$1
   printf -v "$__resultvar" '%s' "ERROR"
   echo "Hello World"
}

returnSimple theResult | cat
echo ${theResult}
echo Done.
```

Unexpected Output:

```
$ ./returnSimple
Hello World

Done.
```

Why does `printf -v` not work in the second case? Should `printf -v` not write the value into the result variable **independent** of whether the output of the function is piped to another process?

Comment: A pipe is distinct from IO redirection.

Comment: @chepner Right, and that is also the reason why I observed that this use case does work with redirection, but not with piping ... fixed that detail in the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See `man bash`, section on `Pipelines`:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

That's why when you write `cmd | cat`, `cmd` receives a copy of variable that it can't modify.

A simple demo:

```
$ test() ((a++))
$ echo $a

$ test
$ echo $a
1
$ test | cat
$ echo $a
1
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I missed ... I just also found that out ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, the same also happens when using `eval $__resultvar="'ERROR'"` instead of the `printf -v` statement. Thus, this is not a `printf` related issue.

Instead, adding a `echo $BASH_SUBSHELL` to both the main script and the function shows that the shell spawns a sub shell in the second case - since it needs to pipe the output from the function to another process. Hence the function runs in a sub shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

returnSimple() {
    local  __resultvar=$1
    echo "Sub shell level: $BASH_SUBSHELL"
    printf -v "$__resultvar" '%s' "ERROR"
}

echo "Sub shell level: $BASH_SUBSHELL"
returnSimple theResult | cat
echo ${theResult}
echo Done.
```

Output:

```
% ./returnSimple.sh
Sub shell level: 0
Sub shell level: 1

Done.
```

This is the reason why any variable assignments from within the function are not passed back to the calling script.